# wordpress single page name

Tags: php, wordpress

assuming this is my custom post type code, on my own theme:

```
    register_post_type( 'wpmon-product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'My Store' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Products' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Products' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Products' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New Products' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Products' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Products' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No products found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in trash' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => 'product'),
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_custom_metaboxes'
        )
    );
```

on my themeplate folder: what should be the name of my single.php php?
is it 'single-wpmon-product.php'? or 'single-product.php'

i tried it both.. but it doesnt work on :(

Answer (score 1):

The template does indeed need to be `single-wpmon-product.php`. As you have probably already seen, the WordPress Codex gives you the guidelines here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates. I've created your custom post_type locally and that template file name works for me.

I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Are you sure you are creating these posts inside of  `My Store` and not `Posts`?

Comment: yes i am '/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=wpmon-product' i am using my theme as child theme only.. after adding an item when i view on the links 'http://localhost/wordpress/product/iphone4/' it does not work....

Comment: ok, what parent theme are you using? I'll try and reproduce the problem you're having

Comment: I'm not too familiar with child themes, but are you using `TEMPLATEPATH` at all? see these support links: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-theme-post-templates and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-template-not-being-applied

Comment: hi i am using the twentyeleven as parent theme, for my new thems

Comment: /*
Theme Name: WPMon e-commerce theme
Theme URI: http://www.mywebsite.com
Description: Child themes
Version: 1.0
Author: Mon
Template: twentyeleven
*/

Comment: Even when I place the custom template in a blank child theme it works, you must have some other template overriding it somewhere. I'm sorry, I don't know what to tell you! Try removing everything else (besides the stylesheet) from the child theme temporarily and deactivate your plugins. Also try cleaning out that custom template except for an h1 tag or something.

Comment: Hi i got it work now... thanks for the tip, i remove everything, and re-install table.. now it works.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the single page name depends on the name of custom post type you Registered . so your single template file for this post type must be single-wpmon-product.php  .

maybe you forgot to call the registration function in "init hook". for example if the function name is :
`function register_myposttype() ;`

so you must call it as
`add_action( 'init', 'register_myposttype' );`